# IOS Notificaton Center Wrong Settings

Tags: ios, push-notification

When my app is freshly installed and I am prompted to allow push notification using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Let say I select "Don't Allow".
When I go into `iPhone settings > Notifications`, I find my app is in the group "In Notification Center" instead of in the group "Not in Notification Center".

If I tap into my app, everything is on. The Notification center is On and the alert style is Banners and both Badge App Icon and Sounds is on. Why is this so?

Furthermore, if I run this code:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

I get `(UIRemoteNotificationType) types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone`.

Why is all these so inconsistent.

Thanks for any help. 
Btw, I am running `IOS 6.1.3`.